# TS - custom iterable - for...of error

Tags: angular, typescript, iterator, for-of-loop

I am trying to implement a custom iterable in my angular app. I am getting this error:
"Type 'Connection' is not an array type or a string type." when I try to iterate trough the class using for..of

I found out, that you can get this error in ES5, when you try to iterate through anything else than an [] or string, using this for..of technique. Is my understanding, that I should be able to do this, because TS is a superset of ES6, which than compiles down to my defined target ES5 in tsconfig.json wrong?

DTO:

```
export class Property{
key: string;
value: any;
}
```

Iterator:

```
import { Property } from './dto/property';

export class PropertyIterator {
data: Property[] = [];
index: number = 0;

constructor(object: Object) {
    Object.entries(object).forEach(
        ([key, value]) => {
            this.data.push({ key, value })
        }
    );
}

next() {

    var result = { value: undefined, done: false }
    if (this.index < this.data.length) {
        result.value = this.data[this.index++];
    } else {
        result.done = true;
        this.index = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Iterable:

```
import { PropertyIterator } from './../../property-iterator';
import { ConnectionBuilder } from './connection-builder';
import { Property } from '../property';

export  class Connection implements Iterable<Property> {


    connectionId: number; //required
    type: string; //required
    username: string; //required
    password: string; //required
    path: string; //required

    serverName: string; //optional
    port: number; //optional

    constructor(builder: ConnectionBuilder){

        this.connectionId = builder.ConnectionId;
        this.type = builder.Type;
        this.username = builder.Username;
        this.password = builder.Password;
        this.path = builder.Path;
        this.serverName = builder.ServerName;
        this.port = builder.Port;   
    }

    [Symbol.iterator](){
        return new PropertyIterator(this);
    }

}
```

Usage, this is where I get the error, this.connection is underlined:

```
  getData(): Property[] {
let info: Property[] = []

for(let value of this.connection){
  info.push(value)
}
```

TSC Version 2.7.2

Comment: You can try to use `... of Array.from(this.connection) ) {...`

Comment: You have a typo in your code `this.conncection`. You probably want that to be `this.connection`

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick .

Comment: The typo was introduced to the code in the process of refactoring, but it was consistent, so that had no other effect than making it a bit ugly. Anyways, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @FeelaV - Which comment "did the trick"?

Comment: The comment of @Mixalloff, I could not tag him on my mobile app, weird.

Answer (score 0):

While the array workaround will work, there's another, more general solution. Since version 2.3, TS actually supports ES2015 iterators for ES3/5 targets but this support is disabled by default. You can enable it by adding the following line in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution, the results were promising, until I got an error at runtime:
"
src/app/connection/connection-info/connection-info.component.ts(42,22): error TS2495: Type 'Connection' is not an array type or a string type.
"

Comment: That is not a runtime error, it's by the TS compiler. If you had Angular CLI running when changing the `tsconfig` file you'll need to restart it before your changes take effect.